# How to split file items into array?

Tags: java, arrays, split, file-handling

I have a file which has data like:

```
Australia,1
Spain,3
Rome,7
Germany,2
```

Now I know we can use split function to seperate the country name and the numbers.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(f);
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line=sc.nextLine();
    String[] teams=line.split(",");
    System.out.println(teams[0]);
}
```

Something like this.
But when I wish to print the first element of array like:

```
    System.out.println(teams[0]);
```

I get the output as:

```
Australia
Ghana
China
Spain
```

What I want is when I try to print:

```
    System.out.println(teams[0]);
```

I only want **Australia** as output.
And when I try:

```
System.out.println[(teams[1]); 
I want output as Spain
```

How can I do it ?

This is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Team {

private String name;
private int ranking;
private int yellowCard;
private int redCard;
int won;
int loss;
int draw;
static String[] arr;
String goalScored;



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getRanking() {
    return ranking;
}

public void setRanking(int ranking) {
    this.ranking = ranking;
}

public int getYellowCard() {
    return yellowCard;
}

public void setYellowCard(int yellowCard) {
    this.yellowCard = yellowCard;
}

public int getRedCard() {
    return redCard;
}

public void setRedCard(int redCard) {
    this.redCard = redCard;
}

public static void readFile(File f) {

    try {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(f);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {

            String line=sc.nextLine();
            String[] teams=line.split(",");
            System.out.println(teams[0]);
//              int count=teams.length;
//              
//              int i=0;
//                  if(i%2 ==0) {
//                      
//                      Team team=new Team();
//                      String teamNames=teams[i];
//                      team.setName(teamNames);
//                      System.out.println(team.getName());
//                  }
            }

        //}
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    File f=new File("files/teams.txt");
    Team.readFile(f);
}

}
```

Comment: Post a working example that generates the output you say you are getting.

Comment: In your code, `teams` represents an array: {country, number}. For each row you print the first element of the array, ie the country. If you only want the first **country**, put every country in a list or an array, and print the first one

Comment: How ?? Can you give an example @HBo

Comment: well, @azro gave a pretty nice answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your print is in `loop` that reads your file, so it prints the name of the country at each row

You need to store them all, and after the `loop` retrieve them like you need, and all that in a `List` because you don't know in advance the size (required to build array)

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    String[] teams = line.split(",");
    list.add(teams[0]);
}
System.out.println(list.get(0));    // Australia
System.out.println(list.get(1));    // Spain
```

---

If you really need an `array` after :

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    //...
}
String[] res = list.toArray(new String[0]);
System.out.println(res[0]);         // Australia
System.out.println(res[1]);         // Spain
```

---

Using **Java 8 Streams** you can do :

```
String[] resArray = Files.readAllLines(f.toPath()).stream()
                         .map(s -> s.split(",")[0])   
                         .toArray(String[]::new);
// or
List<String> resList = Files.readAllLines(f.toPath()).stream()
                            .map(s -> s.split(",")[0])
                            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```